# Visual Studio Just My Code still steps into framework

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I enabled Just My Code in VS 2022, however, when I step in with F11 it takes me into code that's not mine.

I see various modules listed as User Code (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json.dll has User Code set to yes). These show symbol status as loaded. Most others have status of Cannot find or open the PDB file.

This is making debugging laborious. Am I missing some other setting?

Or is this as simple as selecting each module and choosing don't load automatically?

I don't recall doing electing to load these symbols. I did read that to enable stepping into module code I need symbols and the code can't be optimized. But does that mean that if I load symbols and they're not optimized, I have no choice but to step into them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this, the solution for me was to go to Options-Debugging-General and uncheck Suppress JIT optimization on module load.